# mod_wsgi error - class.__dict__ not accessible in restricted mode

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, pyramid

This started biting our ass on our production server really hard. We saw this occasionally (for 1 request per week). Back then we found out it is because of mod_wsgi doing some funky stuff in some configs. As we could not track the reason for the bug, we decided that it did not require instant attention.

However today, on 1 of our production servers this really occurred for 10 % of all server requests; that is 10 % of all server requests failed with this very same error:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=1718): Target WSGI script '/installation/dir/our-program/prod-dispatch.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=1718): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/installation/dir/our-program/prod-dispatch.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/installation/dir/our-program/prod-dispatch.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
    from pyramid.paster import get_app
  File "/installation/dir/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a6-py2.7.egg/pyramid/paster.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pyramid.scripting import prepare
  File "/installation/dir/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a6-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripting.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyramid.config import global_registries
  File "/installation/dir/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a6-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from pyramid.config.assets import AssetsConfiguratorMixin
  File "/installation/dir/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a6-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/assets.py", line 83, in <module>
    @implementer(IPackageOverrides)
  File "/installation/dir/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-3.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/declarations.py", line 480, in __
    classImplements(ob, *self.interfaces)
  File "/installation/dir/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-3.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/declarations.py", line 445, in cl
    spec = implementedBy(cls)
  File "/installation/dir/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-3.8.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/declarations.py", line 285, in im
    spec = cls.__dict__.get('__implemented__')
RuntimeError: class.__dict__ not accessible in restricted mode
```

Ubuntu Precise, 64bit, with latest Apache, mod_wsgi, Python 2.7, using mpm_worker + mod_wsgi in *daemon* mode. This is the only program running on the server and there is only one wsgi interpreter in the config. Is this because of mpm_worker spawning new threads or what? More importantly - how do we fix it.

We have the following to subdivide requests to 4 daemon processes based on a cookie.

```
WSGIPythonOptimize 1

WSGIDaemonProcess sticky01 processes=1 threads=16 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIDaemonProcess sticky02 processes=1 threads=16 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIDaemonProcess sticky03 processes=1 threads=16 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIDaemonProcess sticky04 processes=1 threads=16 display-name=%{GROUP}

<VirtualHost *:81>
    ...
    WSGIRestrictProcess sticky01 sticky02 sticky03 sticky04
    WSGIProcessGroup %{ENV:PROCESS}
    ...

    WSGIScriptAlias / /installation/dir/our-program/prod-dispatch.wsgi        
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has been known for ages that multiple subinterpreters don't play well along C extensions. However, what I did not realize is that the default settings are very unfortunate. [ModWSGI wiki](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIApplicationGroup) clearly states that the default value for WSGIApplicationGroup directive is %{RESOURCE} the effect of which shall be that

> The application group name will be set to the server hostname and port
>   as for the %{SERVER} variable, to which the value of WSGI environment
>   variable SCRIPT_NAME is appended separated by the file separator
>   character.

This means that for each Host: header ever encountered while accessing the server the mod_wsgi kindly spawns a new subinterpreter, for which the C extensions are then loaded.

I had unknowingly triggered the error by accessing localhost.invalid:81 with *links* browser on this local server causing 1 of our 4 WSGIDaemonProcesses to fail for all future incoming requests.

Summa summarum: **always when using mod_wsgi with pyramid or any other framework that uses C extensions, make sure that WSGIApplicationGroup is always set to %{GLOBAL}**. In other words, the result of using the default settings will cause you to shoot yourself in the foot, after which you might want to shoot yourself in the head too.

Comment: It is not all C extensions that have problems, only certain ones. Sometimes this is because of bad coding in the C extensions, other times the issue is that they use simplified API for handling thread states in Python. So although using a daemon process group and forcing use of the main interpreter is a good rule of thumb, it is not always necessary.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarification. However, I still think the %{RESOURCE} default is unfortunate as it creates 2 subinterpreters for the same wsgi script in the same virtual host even when accessing it with both http://127.0.0.1 and http://localhost. It is too magic.

Comment: %{RESOURCE} should use the value of ServerName from the VirtualHost it matched. If it doesn't then there is some issue with the Apache configuration is defined.

Comment: But this is not a NameVirtualHost, just port based, it does not contain ServerName.