# mysql connector missing queue module python3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid, mysql-python

I am working on setting up the pyramid framework on python3.3 virtual env.
For the database connection I use MySQL Connector/Python (SQLAlchemy).

I came across with the problem:

When I try to select records form the database I get the following:

`[Wed Feb 12 09:20:34.373204 2014] [:error] [pid 29351] [remote 127.0.0.1:55376]   File "/home/xxx/wsgi/env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mysql_connector_python-1.1.5-py3.3.egg/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 29, in <module>
    [Wed Feb 12 09:20:34.373237 2014] [:error] [pid 29351] [remote 127.0.0.1:55376]`
`ImportError: No module named queue`

It can't find the module queue, but this works just fine:

```
~/wsgi/env$ bin/python3.3 
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:50:09) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import queue
>>>
```

Where is the problem? There are no symlink in `wsgi/env/lib/python3.3/` for `queue.py`, but if I add it manually, the error still appears

**EDIT 1:**
When I use the pserve command to launch a web server, everything is ok, but with apache2, the one above happens.

Apache config:

```
# Use only 1 Python sub-interpreter.  Multiple sub-interpreters
# play badly with C extensions.  See
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558360/209039
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=user group=staff threads=4 \
   python-path=/home/user/wsgi/env/lib/python3.3/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias /app /home/user/wsgi/env/pyramid.wsgi

<Directory /home/user/wsgi/env>
  WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
 # Order allow,deny
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Very weird. Have you tried running `bin/pshell paster.ini` (replace `paster.ini` with your Pyramid `.ini` file) and then `import mysql` there?

Comment: (env)my@pc:~/wsgi/env$ bin/pshell app/development.ini 
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:50:09) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help" for more information.

Environment:
  app          The WSGI application.
  registry     Active Pyramid registry.
  request      Active request object.
  root         Root of the default resource tree.
  root_factory Default root factory used to create `root`.

>>> import mysql
>>>

Comment: You probably need to point the [WSGIPythonHome](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome) directive to your virtualenv. Otherwise I think it is using your system's Python 2 interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what caused all the problems. I was using mod_wsgi, not compatible with python3.3.
Solved the problem with:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Answer (score 0):

Short story: If your Python3-code relies on the queue-module make sure to import "queue" - not "Queue".

Long story:
I was experiencing a similar issue, while trying to get an automatic restart of my apache-served wsgi-coupled django-application. In my case i took the code sample from https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode and being still a noob first "solved" my problem with the line "import Queue" by adding "from multiprocessing import Queue" - which was obviously wrong as the code sample was actually trying to import the queue from queuelib-module (at least i think so). So the real and somewhat subtle problem was the big "Q" - changing the line to "import queue" solved the problem.